# VirtualBox Drive Resize

Tags: virtualbox, hard-disk

I am trying to ***increase*** a ***dynamically allocated*** drive
in VirtualBox.

Environment:
Windows 10 guest on a Pop!_OS (Ubuntu derivative) host. VirtualBox 6.0. Windows guest configured with a 50 GB dynamic drive.  Trying to increase to 100 GB.  I have over 500 GB available on the host.

Command: `VBoxManage modifyhd "/home/happycoffeebean/Windows/Windows.vdi" --resize 102400`
(Also tried `VBoxManage modifyhd --resize 102400 /home/happycoffeebean/Windows/Windows.vdi"`)

Result:

```
happycoffeebean@pop-os:~$ VBoxManage modifyhd --resize 102400 "/home/happycoffeebean/Windows/Windows.vdi"
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED
VBoxManage: error: Failed to resize medium
VBoxManage: error: Resizing to new size 107374182400 is not yet supported for medium '/home/happycoffeebean/Windows/Windows.vdi'
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_NOT_SUPPORTED (0x80bb0009), component MediumWrap, interface IMedium
VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleModifyMedium(HandlerArg*)" at line 768 of file VBoxManageDisk.cpp
```

What I've tried:

1. Verified that 102400 MB == 102 GB.
2. Calculated 107374182400 MB is over a petabyte.  Correct number (107 GB) if calculated from bytes. Unclear on this inconsistency.
3. Googled the errors, only came up with answers pertaining to people trying to decrease disk space and / or using fixed allocation configs.
4. Googled the petabyte number, found a Russian forum with no answer.
5. Slept on it, left it for a day or two. Same result.  Left it for another day.  Still nothing.

---

Response to freddy:
Output of
`VBoxManage showmediuminfo /home/happycoffeebean/Windows/Windows.vdi`:

```
UUID:           7921c7ce-fee5-4667-aab1-bc34fc62b079
Parent UUID:    base
State:          locked read
Type:           normal (base)
Location:       /home/happycoffeebean/Windows/Windows.vdi
Storage format: VDI
Format variant: fixed default
Capacity:       51200 MBytes
Size on disk:   51202 MBytes
Encryption:     disabled
In use by VMs:  Windows (UUID: 23e44ce0-e866-4a55-9452-45e407cf693d) [Base Windows Install (UUID: aaadd1bb-c95b-4a2c-91b8-67e7f530ab17)]
Child UUIDs:    e7620931-e60d-421c-894b-b820644e8134
```

Screenshot of VBox control center:
[image: What I'm Seeing]

Comment: (1) Actually, 102400 MiB = 100 GiB, which equals 107 374 182 400 bytes. (2) Are you saying that `VBoxManage` displayed that message *but didn’t exit?*

Comment: @close voter: This is not a Windows question; it is a VirtualBox question.  (Unless you can demonstrate that this problem would not occur with a Linux guest; in which case, please provide evidence.)

Comment: Please add the output of `VBoxManage showmediuminfo /home/happycoffeebean/Windows/Windows.vdi`.

Comment: Try checking the vdi format as per [this post](https://www.yinfor.com/2015/05/virtualbox-resize-hard-disk-error-vbox_e_not_supported.html). Same error.

Comment: I see after running freddy's command I seem like an idiot.  It's not what's shown in my VirtualBox settings.  I will try to post the graphic here, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the gui reports something different and why the disk is full to its maximum.

You have enough disk space, try to clone and resize the disk as in [bu5hman's comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/531941/virtualbox-drive-resize#comment984636_531941):

1. Clone the disk:

   ```
   VBoxManage clonemedium /home/happycoffeebean/Windows/Windows.vdi /home/happycoffeebean/Windows/winclone.vdi
   ```
2. Optional check. The clone should have type `dynamic default` now:

   ```
   VBoxManage showmediuminfo /home/happycoffeebean/Windows/winclone.vdi
   ```
3. Resize the clone:

   ```
   VBoxManage modifymedium /home/happycoffeebean/Windows/winclone.vdi --resize 102400
   ```
4. Resize the guest partition(s):

   - Swap the disk images in your guest.
   - Insert an ISO image of your favourite partition manager (maybe [gparted](https://gparted.org/download.php)) into the virtual CD/DVD drive, start the guest and resize the Windows partition(s).
5. Delete the old disk image.

Comment: Is there any reason why the clone wouldn't include all the installed applications and files as the original drive?  The cloned .vdi (before using gparted to expand), with the exception of a .txt file on the desktop, looks like a fresh install of Windows.

Comment: No. You shouldn't notice any difference to the original except for the different .vdi name and the bigger drive. Is there any chance you restored an old snapshot by mistake before you started the machine? What is also strange is that the old .vdi was completely full... Is the actual size of the clone still 50GB?

Comment: No, the resize command completed normally, and I attached it to the existing machine, booted into gparted and extended the 50 GB partition to fill the 100 GB space.  When I rebooted, I found the very early OS.  I don't think I could have mistakenly restored a snapshot, since it's not my habit, and didn't even have the GUI loaded when I went through the cloning procedure.  I'm starting to think this image was doomed from the start.

Comment: Disregard.  I realize that I've been using a snapshot image since day one.  I installed everything, then saved the snapshot.   Unless there is some way to clone a snapshot, it looks like nothing can be done to resize the drive in this case.